# Fazer Transição Da Evolução Javascript Para Cross Browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

Vejo esta carência, que pessoas como eu auto-didata, tenta entender.

A questão é - Hoje em dia algumas features já são suportadas pelos principais navegadores **HTML5, CSS3, DOM, APIs e ECMAScript...** sendo muito **utilizado por parte dos programadores *Javascript***, não é o meu caso, mas você pode ser um deles. No entanto, me deparo sempre com alguma resposta aqui utilizando-os.

Sempre ha necessidade em fazer a transição(transcrever) esta(s) funcionalidade(s), para algum *método* aplamente compatível. Mas como sempre sou um aprendiz, hoje, abro uma questão indiferente das outras feitas por mim.

***A idéia aqui apresentada é dar uma lista de comparações do que pode ser substituído por outro método nativo do Javascript, na falta de suporte ao navegador.***

## Exemplo

No HTML 5, temos como nativo `praceholder` para campo de texto. Que limpa o texto definido no `value` quando **em focu**.

Este mesmo efeito pode ser conseguido com *Javascript* puro da seguinte forma:

```
 <input value="digite aqui" type="text"
 onblur="if(this.value == '') {this.value = 'digite aqui';}" 
 onfocus="if(this.value == 'digite aqui') {this.value = '';}" />
```

Em resumo - significa utilizar método e propriedades própria do próprio *Javascript* ao invés de APIs elegantes e tal.

> Acho que, **HTML5, CSS3, DOM, APIs e ECMAScript...** numa maneira geral seria melhor aplicado em um projeto específico(APP) e/ou determinado aparelho, tipo usuário do Android, Windows Phone ou iOS, mas não para um todo como a Web, lembrando que nem todos possuem computadores veloz e de última geração, e com o passar do tempo Firefox, Google Chrome, Opera e Safari dentre outros menos, atualização seus Navegadores periódicamente, chegando num dado momento que, temos que efetuar uma Compra de um novo Micro Computador, porque a nova atulização pode nem mais rodar rendondo no velho PC, as vezes nem instala.

No que se diz respeito, ONGs, entidades sem fins lucrativos não tem condições de comprar um novo aparelho, eles sobrevivem de doações, correto?

Ai, é que eu entro no cenário. Se eu estou a desenvolver um projeto Web e desejo impactar a maior quantidade de internautas em contato ao site/blog, como vou abrir mão de **linguagem Cross Browser**. Não posso!

Se alguém compreendeu a Pergunta deixe sua resposta ou comentário.

Comment: Posso não ter compreendido sua pergunta da forma correta, mas eu acredito que quando você tem um projeto a fazer para alguma entidade definida, você tem em mãos o que pode ou não ser feito. Tudo depende da análise de requisitos e das limitações impostas por você mesmo em seu software, particularmente, em sistemas públicos eu mantenho o máximo de compatibilidade possível*, porém para instituições que o sistema é interno e a empresa tem controle das máquinas, sempre faço com a tecnologia mais atual, é tudo uma questão de analisar para quem você irá desenvolver.

Comment: Ressaltei a questão da "máxima compatibilidade possível*", isto é, se nem a Microsoft dá suporte para versões mais antigas do Internet Explorer, por que eu daria? Tem que ter um balanço entre isso, e otimizar a aplicação resolverá vários problemas para usuários com sistemas lentos. Algumas bibliotecas podem "resolver" problemas de compatibilidade com algumas rotinas, como o jQuery, porém elas matam o desempenho,são lentas, e no caso dos browsers mais atuais, o próprio código nativo do Javascript pode substituí-lo.

Comment: @DiegoHenriqueGuilherme, como disse na minha resposta, você deve usar um `Polyfill`, para este caso em especifico, você pode utilizar o seguinte script [ES5-DOM-SHIM](https://github.com/termi/ES5-DOM-SHIM), então poderá usar o `addEventListener` e `querySelectorAll` até no IE6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está indo pelo caminho contrário. Pense primeiro no usuário (leia-se: público-alvo) depois defina a tecnologia.

> Quer entregar software pra ONGs em lugares remotos que possuem equipamentos precários, internet lenta e pessoal pouco capacitado tecnologicamente?

Não use recursos avançados. Pense em HTML puro sem muita frescura.

> Está fazendo um software para ser usado por clientes de um banco, portanto segurança é uma preocupação?

Define estritamente quais navegadores e quais versões podem ser usadas e use os recursos disponíveis nelas.

> Está fazendo um site para web em geral (notícias, receitas, etc.)?

Analise o perfil de usuários do site.

O Google Analytics, por exemplo, disponibiliza gráficos que mostram a porcentagem de usuários que acessam o seu site de cada navegador, desktop/mobile, etc. Você pode então focar, por exemplo, em escrever código compatível com 95% dos navegadores desse relatório.

Os outros 5%? Eles provavelmente vão ter um uso parcial e vão ter que ter paciência.

## Preenchendo as lacunas

Ao definir a lista de navegadores suportados, você pode adotar basicamente três estratégicas para cada recurso que precisa usar:

1. Usar os recursos disponíveis nas versões mais novas e deixar o recurso ausente das versões mais antigas. Seria o caso de ter o placeholder no Chrome, mas não em certas versões do IE, por exemplo.
2. Usar os recursos das versões novas e prover *shims* ou *polyfills*, que simulam aquelas funcionalidades usando alguma mágica.
3. Basear-se nas versões mais antigas e só usar os recursos que estão disponíveis em todos os navegadores.

A opção #1 é interessante pois beneficia quem tem o navegador mais novo. Quem não tem, não vê a funcionalidade melhor, mas consegue usar o site sem problemas. Eles não vão ficar chateados, pois *"o que os olhos não vêem, o coração não sente"*. :P

A opção #2 provê as mesmas funcionalidades mais avançadas para todos, mas envolve mais trabalho e provavelmente vai deixar o site mais lento para carregar, já que há scripts adicionais para dar conta do trabalho-extra que o navegador não faz.

A opção #3 é a mais segura, mas pode impactar negativamente a experiência do usuário.

## A decisão

Ela cabe a você - ou aos arquitetos/líderes do projeto, ou à pessoa que decide se ela vai pagar a você mais ou menos pelo trabalho. :)

O importante é saber que todas as opções, ou uma mistura delas, são válidas para diferentes contextos.

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que entendi da sua pergunta, você gostaria de uma lista de funcionalidades e quais são os browsers (com versão dita) que aquela funcionalidade está implementada. Existe um site que faz justamente isso, inclusive ele diz até se uma funcionalidade está implementada parcialmente.

http://caniuse.com/

Comment: Estava com esse link no Ctrl+C pra postar aqui.. hehe

Comment: Haha, imagino. Eu parei para lembrar de tanto tempo que não o uso, atualmente eu uso polyfills para tudo... gosto de escrever em ES6 e usar pré-processadores para CSS e HTML.

Comment: Show sua dica. Valeu

Answer (score 2):

Diego, sei que é importante dá suporte à maior fatia possível dos usuários, por um outro lado é difícil manter a compatibilidade com navegadores antigos.

Um exemplo deste dilema é o próprio `jQuery`, que por algum tempo manteve duas versões, a 1.x e a 2.x, sendo que a principal diferença entre elas era o suporte à versões do `IE` que sequer são mais mantidas pela `Microsoft`.

Mas manter este tipo de compatibilidade tem o seu preço, a versão 1.x do jQuery é maior e mais pesada que a versão 1.x, como resultado ela requer mais tempo para ser baixada e mais processamento do cliente.

Neste caso vale realmente a pena penalizar ~96% dos usuários por causa dos ~4% restantes, lembre-se que oficialmente nem a `Microsoft` dá suporte ao `IE 6~8` e logo só dara á suporte a versão mais atual (`Edge` ou `IE 11`, dependendo do OS).

Então te aconselho a traçar uma linha e definir qual a versão minima de cada navegador que planeja da suporte.

Agora vamos à questão das `features`, então antes de utilizar uma `feature`, você deve verificar se a mesma é compartível com a versão minima do navegador que você definiu a pouco, e se não for compatível, deverá tomar a decisão, desistir dela ou adicionar um script de `Polyfill`.

Na minha opinião a melhor maneira de implementar um script de polyfill, é criar um `IIFE (Immediately-invoked function expression)`, no começo da mesma fazer uma detecção da `feature`, caso a mesma não seja encontrada, então implemente a mesma.

Exemplo, você decidiu dá suporte ao `IE9` e achou legal utilizar a `tag template` no seu site, porém descobriu que o mesmo não dá suporte à mesma, neste caso, você terá de abrir mão do `<template>` ou usar um `Polyfill` para que o seu sistema de entenda esta `tag`.

segue um exemplo de `Polyfill` para a `tag` `template` do HTML5 retirado do seguinte [repositório](https://github.com/jeffcarp/template-polyfill).:

```
(function () {
  if ('content' in document.createElement('template')) {
    return;
  }

  var templates = document.getElementsByTagName('template');
  var plateLen = templates.length;

  for (var x = 0; x < plateLen; ++x) {
    var template = templates[x];
    var content = template.childNodes;
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    while (content[0]) {
      fragment.appendChild(content[0]);
    }

    template.content = fragment;
  }  
})();
```

Comment: Sobre polyfills: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills